# System of 3 equations with 3 unknowns with 6 solutions

Tags: linear-algebra

I was trying to solve this equation that I constructed $$x^3 - 6x^2 + 11x - 6 = 0$$
I know the solutions is 1, 2 and 3. But I wanted to see if I could solve the equation, so I messed around a bit and came ended up with this system of equations:
$$a+b+c=6$$
$$ab+ac+bc=11$$
$$abc=6$$
Where $a,b,c$ is the roots of the equation, I know the solutions is the 6 permutations of assigning 1,2,3 to $a,b,c$ and verified this with wolfram alpha.

My question is, how did wolfram alpha come to this conclusion? There is no show solution button on this query to wolfram alpha.

Comment: Setting up a 3 variable system like you did is unlikely to be easier to solve than the original in my opinion. As you have already noticed you get a combinatorial explosion in the number of solutions.

Comment: @amWhy What I am guessing happened is the OP wrote $(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)$ and then expanded it and collected powers of $x$. The question is about the system that results from that.

Comment: Yes, @TimSeguine, I suspect you are right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wolfram Alpha probably just came back to the original problem of finding the roots
of the polynomial.

$$a+b+c=A$$
$$ab+ac+bc=B$$
$$abc=C$$
is equivalent to
$$
(a,b,c)\in \{(x_{\sigma(1)},x_{\sigma(2)}, x_{\sigma(3)})|
\sigma\in S_3 \}
\\
x_i \text{ roots of } x^3-Ax^2+Bx-C = 0
$$

Comment: I can't say for sure how Wolfram|Alpha (i.e., Mathematica) solves the original cubic (although it probably just puts the coefficients into the cubic formula), but I can say that when confronted with the symmetric system on the roots, it uses `GroebnerBasis` followed by whatever method it uses to solve the resulting cubic--i.e., it essentially does what you are saying it does.

Comment: @heropup If I were programming it, I would check for rational roots, and if there were none, calculate them based on the cubic formula.

Answer (score 0):

This is Newtons symmetric polynomials, if $ f $ is a monomial ie $f=x^n+a_1x^{n-1}+...+a_0$ with n roots $\alpha_1 ,...,\alpha_n$ then we can write $f$ as $ f=(x-\alpha_1)...(x-\alpha_n)$

Expanding these and comparing with the original coefficients of $f$ we get the system of $n$ equations like you have put.